# @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native still uses @react-native-community/async-storage which has been deprecated

Tags: react-native, npm, deprecated, tensorflow.js, asyncstorage

Error message:

```
Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/async-storage" from "node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native/dist/async_storage_io.js"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "objectdetect",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.2.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.1.0-alpha.1",
    "expo": "~48.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "^13.2.1",
    "expo-gl": "^12.4.0",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If we want to use this npm library

```
@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native
```

then do we have to use the deprecated version of the following npm library?

```
@react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```